# How many distinct combinations can be made from a complex group?

Tags: math, combinations

By complex group I mean a group where not all values are distinct. That is, if an ordinary group would be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 (In which the amount of different combinations is 7C0+7C1+7C2...=2^7), then an example for a complex group is 1,1,1,3,3,5,7. How to calculate how many different combinations (where order does not matter) can be generated from such groups?

EDIT: to clarify this. If for example we take 7C1=7, then we find that it cannot be applied to complex groups. That's because we get 7 different groups, but some of them are equal (1=1=1 and 3=3), so actually there are only 4 different groups (1,3,5,7).

In other words, in the simple case of 1,1,2, simple 2^3 would consider these groups:

{},{1},{1},{2},{1,1},{1,2},{1,2},{1,1,2} = 8

What I need, is a way to calculate the amount of different groups (I consider {1,2}={2,1}). That would consider these:

{},{1},{2},{1,1},{1,2},{1,1,2} = 6

Comment: Order doesn't matter, but I assume you're looking for distinct elements in each combination (no repeats)? Otherwise you're back at `2^7`. In the case of distinct elements then isn't it the same as the problem of number of subsets of 1,3,5,7, which is `2^4`? In other words, the answer is `2^N` where `N` is the number of distinct elements in the original set.

Comment: This does not take into consideration groups like 1,1 or 3,3

Comment: Oh so you do want to count, in the case of original set of 1,1, the subgroup 1,1 then? That wasn't clear to me initially. So in the case of 1,1, you have three: (1) empty, (2) 1, and (3) 1,1. Is that what you mean? Whereas in the case of 1,2, you have four.

Comment: The usual mathematical term for this is _multiset_.  If there are no repetitions, then you have a _set_.  But multisets are less common than sets, so you generally would need to describe what you're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the product of the (counts+1) of unique elements in the set.

`Explanation :` For each unique number it can occur from `zero` to `k` times where `k` is the number of repetition of the number. So there are `[0..k]` i.e. total `(k+1)` options for each unique number. So the it is the product of the (counts+1) of unique elements in the set.

For `{1,1,2}`: count+1 for `1` = `2+1` = `3` and count+1 for `2` = `1+1` = `2`
So the answer is `3*2 = 6`.

For `{1,1,1,3,3,5,7}` it is `(3+1)*(2+1)*(1+1)*(1+1) = 4*3*2*2 = 48`

A python3 code:

```
>>> import collections
>>> A = [1,1,1,3,3,5,7]
>>> def countComplexGroups(A):
...     count = collections.Counter(A)
...     rt = 1
...     for i in count: rt*=count[i]+1
...     return rt
...
>>> print(countComplexGroups(A))
48
```